# Increase Query Time Out int WCF Services

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, wcf

I have a very lengthy SQL query which takes up to 2 mint for execution. I used this query in my WCF services and it gives this exception 
`Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding`. it could not resolve after adding this code to my web config file

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding openTimeout="00:10:00"
             closeTimeout="00:10:00"
             sendTimeout="00:10:00"
             receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>


<services>
  <service name="longTimeoutService"
    behaviorConfiguration="longTimeoutBehavior">
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost/longtimeout/"
      binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="longTimeoutBinding" />
  </service>
</services>
```

how can I handle this issue please guide me. thanks

Comment: Did you set the timeout for both, client and server configuration files?

Comment: Extend the query execution timeout, check out this page for timeout info "https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout(v=vs.110).aspx"